# Auto-post photos on Facebook page

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create an Android app in C# which auto-post specific pictures from my gallery on my facebbok page. So I will have a set of 7 pictures, I want from the app to post everyday a specific picture of those 7 so that in Monday the app auto-post pic1 then in Tuesday it post pic2 at the same pre-determined time. The next week it repeat the same work. In my app I want to specify the folder or album from which it is going to pick the pictures to post them on Facebook and to specify the time to auto-post the picture (like 4:00 pm).

Here's my code:

```
private static void PostToPage(string message, string pageAccessToken)
{
var fb = new FacebookClient(pageAccessToken);
var argList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
argList["message"] = message;
fb.Post("feed", argList);
}
```

This code just post a message on my facebook page, how can I edit it to post a specific image instead of message ? How can I implement something similar to alarm to post everyday at the same time (working in background) the specific picture of the day ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `feed` endpoint, use the `photos` endpoint to post photos.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/